# проблема с парсингом xml на python

Tags: c#, python-3.x, xml

начал учить python и обработку xml документов на этом языке, но столкнулся с проблемой выбора библиотек, а следовательно и с обработкой документа вовсе. Был период когда я писал на C# и там вытяжка из xml тех данных, которые мне были нужны имела вид:

```
        XmlNodeList xmlNode = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("rank");

        var xmlNodeinList = xmlNode.Cast<XmlNode>().Select(x => x.InnerText).ToList();

        var res = string.Join("\n", xmlNodeinList.ToArray());
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно переписать данный фрагмент кода на python или как получить данные со всех тэгов 'rank' документа и поместить их в строку. Заранее спасибо. Сам xml ниже(количество узлов неограниченно):

```html
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>
```

Comment: А чем `XPath` плох, что вы фигачите разбор `xml` через `linq`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `Python` есть `xml.etree.ElementTree`, вполне годная для разбора `xml` вещь. Например:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import fromstring

xdoc='''<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>
'''

print(*[x.find('rank').text for x in fromstring(xdoc).findall('country')])
```

Comment: спасибо большое, работает, а не подскажете как это можно сделать без циклов и возможно ли вообще???

Comment: @ЕвгенийПарчевский, изучайте `XPath` - более мощного "механизма" разбора `xml` не найдете.